# Subreport leaving blank space when using keep together

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

Firstly apologies for the lack of image, since i don't have enough rep to attach of images and had to make do with text drawings

I have an issue with SSRS 2008 where I can’t seem to get the keep together property of my report working correctly.
This is how the report currently looks

Page 1:

```
----------------------------------------------
    7.7 
    7.7.1 
    7.7.2
    7.7.3 
    7.7.4 
    7.7.5 







----------------------------------------------
```

Page 2:

```
----------------------------------------------
    7.8 
    7.8.1 
    7.8.2
    7.8.3 
    7.8.4 
    7.8.5 
    ||||||||||||||||||||||||||
    ||||||||||Image|||||||||||
    ||||||||||||||||||||||||||

    7.9
    7.9.1
    7.9.2

----------------------------------------------
```

7.8 to 7.8.5 including the image are all in a sub-report with the keep together property set to true.
Most of page 1 is left empty as the entire sub-report cannot fit onto the space that is left on page 1 and moves onto page 2.

Is it possible to get 7.7 and as much of 7.8 to fit onto one page?

Answer (score 0):

The subreport is a separate and distinct container within your report body or table.  When paginating, SSRS will try to keep inner objects together before considering outer objects.

In other words, if 7.7-7.8.5 cannot fit on a single page, the logical container break is the start of subreport.

If the subreport can't fit on a page by itself, it may share the first page with 7.7, but that level of paging is handled by the renderer.